# Can I use iTunes credit to help subsidise buy hardware in Apple online store?

Tags: itunes, hardware, apple-store

I am thinking about buying an iPad Pro or MacBook Air (Skylake), as a first time buyer of Apple hardware.

I was wondering if I can use iTunes credit balance to help subsidise/buy this hardware in Apple Online store?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. One can only use iTunes credit to buy iTunes Store content and apps, not hardware. I think that it says that on the card itself in fine print, but I could be wrong.

I couldn't find an official statement from Apple, but here's something from the Apple support community: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2592711?start=0&tstart=0